# Not able to update data into database with this trigger

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_or_cl_sup_line
   BEFORE UPDATE OF line_num
   ON line
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   n_out       NUMBER;
   n_seqnum    NUMBER;

   CURSOR cur_cmpnt (c_lineid NUMBER)
   IS
      SELECT cmpnt_id
        FROM component
       WHERE line_id = c_lineid;

   n_cmpntid   NUMBER;
   v_inuser    VARCHAR2 (30);
BEGIN
   p_pause_triggers (n_out);

   IF n_out = 1
   THEN
      RETURN;
   END IF;

   n_out := 0;

   SELECT user_name
     INTO v_inuser
     FROM current_info
    WHERE session_id = USERENV ('SESSIONID');

   IF f_etf_check = 'Y'
   THEN
      p_or_sup ('TR_OR_CL_SUP_line', 'LINE_ID', :new.line_id);
   ELSE
      NULL;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RAISE;
END tr_or_cl_sup_line;
```

This trigger is already exists into database but when I am trying to update data in LINE table through Update query throwing an error:

> ORA-01403: no data found
>
> ORA-06512: at "ZOR_1.TR_OR_CL_SUP_LINE", line 1
>
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ZOR_1.TR_OR_CL_SUP_LINE'

Comment: SELECT user_name INTO v_INuser   FROM current_info 
 WHERE session_id = USERENV('SESSIONID'); This may not be producing a row.

Comment: after removing this, still getting the same error

Comment: Ruling this out, there are two other places this error might arise.  P_pause_triggers(n_Out); and P_OR_sup ('TR_OR_CL_SUP_line',               'LINE_ID',:NEW.line_id);

Comment: Remove EXCEPTION section, it is useless (the way it currently looks like). Won't fix your NO-DATA-FOUND, though.

Comment: @Littlefoot i did that also but didn't get the solution

Comment: @ArtBajji i removed this from the code and got this error:
 ORA-04098: trigger 'ZOR.TR_OR_CL_SUP_LINE' is invalid and failed 
  re-validation

Comment: @ArtBajji Can I Disable the trigger?
if I am disabbling the trigger then update is working fine nut i want to know about the impacts

Comment: @S.A. - if you have removed the exception handler then you should see more useful info in the error message - which line it's actually failing on. If whatever you've changed is stopping it recompiling then look in `user_errors` to see why.

Comment: As Alex and Littlefoot suggested, after removing the exception section, what error are you getting? Can you pls paste that here?

Comment: @AlexPoole when i removed the error it is not impacting on anything the same error is coming
ORA-01403: no data found

ORA-06512: at "ZOR_1.TR_OR_CL_SUP_LINE", line 1

ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ZOR_1.TR_OR_CL_SUP_LINE'

Comment: @AlexPoole but if I disable the trigger and then update , after that enable the trigger- this scenario is working fine but i dnt know how its gonna impact in future on database

Comment: It isn't telling you the line number before the ORA-01403 message? (The trigger is presumably there for a reason and doing something important; disabling doesn't affect the database exactly but may affect your data integrity, so that isn't a viable workaround unless you get business agreement that it is no longer needed.)

Comment: its is telling at line 1

Comment: Regarding your error, " ORA-04098: trigger 'ZOR.TR_OR_CL_SUP_LINE' is invalid and failed re-validation" are there any compilation errors? Please paste the error.

Comment: @ArtBajji Regarding ORA-04098 i am getting the below cause and action:
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'ZOR.TR_OR_CL_SUP_LINE' is invalid and failed re-validation

04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"

*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was   found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization  failed for the trigger.


*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

Comment: following the above if i am disabling the Trigger and unable to delete the Table

Comment: The trigger seems to have compilation errors. It cannot be executed. Recompile the trigger and use show errors to see what the compilation error is and paste the compilation error here. Hope this helps.

Comment: Following Error is coming:-        Error(1,437): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge